# What really causes PHP MySQL library version differs from your MySQL server version?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

This message appears in PhpMyAdmin. Often after some update.

There are already a lot of similar questions. One typical answer is "update your libs".
But in the end I still see a lot of people who can't solve it. (myself included)

I've tried to reinstall everything from scratch but it's still there and I get this exact version error:

> Your PHP MySQL library version 5.5.34 differs from your MySQL server
>   version 5.1.69.

I've added the output of my packages list. Everything looks correct. Or so I think. I don't understand where this 5.1.69 version comes from. I don't have much knowledge of linux / server setup.

Is there any linux/server wizard who can help? thank you : )

> [root@server bin]# yum list installed | grep mysql
>
> @remi     compat-mysql51.x86_64               5.1.54-1.el6.remi
>   @remi     mysql.x86_64                        5.5.34-1.el6.remi
>   @remi     mysql-libs.x86_64                   5.5.34-1.el6.remi
>   @remi     mysql-server.x86_64                 5.5.34-1.el6.remi
>   @remi     php-mysql.x86_64                    5.4.20-1.el6.remi
>
> [root@server bin]# yum list installed | grep php
>
> @remi     php.x86_64                          5.4.20-1.el6.remi
>   @remi     php-bcmath.x86_64                   5.4.20-1.el6.remi
>   @remi     php-cli.x86_64                      5.4.20-1.el6.remi
>   @remi     php-common.x86_64                   5.4.20-1.el6.remi
>   @remi     php-fpm.x86_64                      5.4.20-1.el6.remi
>   @remi     php-gd.x86_64                       5.4.20-1.el6.remi
>   @remi     php-imap.x86_64                     5.4.20-1.el6.remi
>   @remi     php-ldap.x86_64                     5.4.20-1.el6.remi
>   @remi     php-magickwand.x86_64               1.0.9.2-4.el6.remi
>   @remi     php-magpierss.noarch                0.72-6.el6
>   @epel     php-mbstring.x86_64                 5.4.20-1.el6.remi
>   @remi     php-mcrypt.x86_64                   5.4.20-1.el6.remi
>   @remi     php-mssql.x86_64                    5.4.20-1.el6.remi
>   @remi     php-mysql.x86_64                    5.4.20-1.el6.remi
>   @remi     php-odbc.x86_64                     5.4.20-1.el6.remi
>   @remi     php-pdo.x86_64                      5.4.20-1.el6.remi
>   @remi     php-pear.noarch                     1:1.9.4-12.el6.remi.1
>   @remi     php-php-gettext.noarch              1.0.11-4.el6.remi
>   @remi     php-recode.x86_64                   5.4.20-1.el6.remi
>   @remi     php-shout.x86_64                    0.9.2-9.el6.remi
>   @remi     php-snmp.x86_64                     5.4.20-1.el6.remi
>   @remi     php-soap.x86_64                     5.4.20-1.el6.remi
>   @remi     php-tcpdf.noarch                    6.0.031-1.el6.remi
>   @remi     php-tcpdf-dejavu-sans-fonts.noarch  6.0.031-1.el6.remi
>   @remi     php-tidy.x86_64                     5.4.20-1.el6.remi
>   @remi     php-xml.x86_64                      5.4.20-1.el6.remi
>   @remi     php-xmlrpc.x86_64                   5.4.20-1.el6.remi
>   @remi     phpMyAdmin.noarch                   4.0.6-1.el6.remi

The configuration I'm running is
CentOs 6.4 
nginx/1.4.2
Database client version: libmysql - 5.5.34
PHP extension: mysqli
Localhost via UNIX socket

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your php-mysql package has been linked against an older MySQL client library. It's strongly suggested to install php-mysqlnd, see http://www.webtatic.com/packages/php54/. Then restart your web server.

Comment: Perdon my noobness, does that mean that the problem actually is due to a mistake on my part, or something wrong with the packages in the remi repo? I will check the webtatic repo, thx :)

Comment: I would say that the mistake was done by whoever created the php-mysql package. However, if you install the php-mysqlnd package, PHP will no longer use this outdated MySQL library.

Comment: I realize this is a bit old, I needed to use `php5-mysqlnd`

Comment: Thanks @billynoah. Yeah, exact package names may vary, and PHP 7 should be released in a few months; expect another package name change.

Comment: Sorry, is `php5-mysqlnd` something to be installed *in addition to* `php5-mysql` or *instead of*?

Comment: @ButtleButkus it should be installed in addition to php5-mysql.

Comment: It doesn't work for me when installing in addition though? I get a conflict error.