# Database client version in PHPMyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I installed mysql 5.6 all packages completely and I have the updated PHPMyadmin and PHP 7.0 and have latest php7.0-mysql library installed

My server is showing the version no. as MySQL 5.6 when test from mysql terminal as well as in PHPMyadmin.

But, the database client version is showing somewhere around 5.0xxx

[image]

I browsed through and saw that I had to update mysqlnd
([What really causes PHP MySQL library version differs from your MySQL server version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959539/what-really-causes-php-mysql-library-version-differs-from-your-mysql-server-vers))

But I am not sure how to proceed. What should I do? Thanks in advance

Running Ubuntu, Apache2

Comment: The version number 5.0.12-dev refers to the [mysqlnd driver](http://docs.php.net/mysqlnd) version, not the mysql server or libmysql. "What should I do?" - Nothing, except maybe being happy about using the ([currently](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.0.3/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd.h#L25)) latest and greatest mysqlnd version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Server and MySQL Client `mysqld` are two different executable programs, with different versions. MySQL don't always need to update the client tools every time there is a new server release.

there may still be newer versions of the library, and the link I post below shows how to do it, however you are unlikely to encounter any issues.

Please refer to [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357909/your-php-mysql-library-version-differs-from-your-mysql-server-version)
Quote

> In theory, this should not cause any real problem : minor versions
>   tend to be compatible ; but you might need to update the library
>   that's used by PHP ; maybe some package like "libmysql", or something
>   like that (I don't have a Debian machine)

Is the other system with PHP 5.6 a different OS than ubuntu? I believe the issue is that the different packages that you download with different OS's will be packaged with different libraries, this may be for various reasons, such as compatibility with the OS.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer but in another system where I run PHP 5.6 it shows database client version as  libmysql - 5.6.28

So, isnt the library I am using outdated?

Comment: Please check my edit for another SO question with a better overview. You can update the library, however unless there is something specific which was fixed in one of the releases, it is unlikely to affect the way PHP connect to mysql

Comment: the different system also runs ubuntu.. the only change in that system is the version of php.. anyways, thank you. I just wanted to know this cause 5.0 seems old